# Dynamic segments for route on index in ember

Tags: ember.js

I have an error when I try to get to URL "/posts" in my Ember app. I get a following error:

```
Uncaught Error: More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: posts.index
```

Which is really puzzling, because there is no dynamic segment for index, my routes look like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('posts', function() {
        this.route('new');
        this.route('show', {
            path: ':post_id'
        });
    });
});
```

part of the model (models/posts.js):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
let Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    author: DS.attr('string'),
    content: DS.attr('string')
});

Post.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Random text",
            author: "Someone new",
            content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium aspernatur quam qui commodi beatae placeat ducimus aliquam veritatis ullam sed! Sit assumenda aspernatur sunt harum accusamus, repellat labore! Repellendus, corporis!"
        }
    ]
});

export default Post;
```

My link which I use to get to /posts:

```
{{link-to 'Posts' 'posts'}}
```

Additional info: I am using ember-cli-cordova, so my environment.js contains "defaultLocationType: 'auto'" and I am also using fixtures, so I have a following adapter:

```
export default DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
  host: config.apiUrl
});
```

Does anybody see any problem which would cause the error? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

My post route (routes/posts/index.js) looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('post');
    }
});
```

When I comment out the line where I am getting data from the store, everything works fine, so it looks that the problem is somehow connected with the usage of fixtures maybe. I'll try to create the minimum example on ember  jsBin, when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly typo at the end - from the error message, I was focusing on the model and route of the index and forgot on a template itself. There is an "each" iterator in which I am creating a link to a detail of the post and there was a typo in a link-to, I had "{{#link-to "posts" post}}" instead of "{{#link-to "posts.show" post}}".

Comment: Ah ok. You should mark your answer as the correct answer so people see it when they find this page.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `{{link-to 'posts'}}` instead of `{{link-to 'Posts' 'posts'}}`, because you don't have dymanic segments in `posts` route.

Comment: I am using link-to as an inline helper, so the first parameter is just a text for 'a' element, the second one is the name of route. According to documentation on ember site here http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/links/ this is possible. So the link-to should be ok.

Comment: Did you try to just type posts url in browser? Did it work?

Comment: The inline helper described in the question should work - here it is in an [Ember JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/secaqijeto/edit?html,js,output). Are you doing any sort of redirecting or replacing or URLs in your PostsRoute? Can you post the PostsRoute too or reproduce the error in a JSBin?

Comment: I have updated my question with new information - problem is connected to my model probably, furthemore I will create some minimum example on ember jsBin when I get home (few hours).

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce it in ember jsbin, I Couldn't create exact but minified copy of this concrete part of the project. Well...I'll be searching further...